# (Python) Creating a basic "enter your password" program

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a basic program which asks for a user to enter and then re-enter a password. If it matches, then it will print "Password created". If it doesn't, it will continue to ask the user to retry until the passwords match.

This is what I have so far; I know a loop and  at least one other "if" statements is needed, but I don't know how to do it.

```
password=raw_input("please select a password")
password_again=raw_input("please re-type your password")
loop=raw_input("Password does not match. Please try again")
if password_again==password:
      print("password created")
else: raw_input(loop)
```

Help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

**I think using getpass module would be a wise decision:** It will Prompt the user for a password without echoing

```
from getpass import getpass

print "Please select a password: "
passwd = getpass()

print "Please re-type your password: "
if passwd == getpass():
    print "password created"
else:
    print "Password does not match. Please try again"
```

Output:

```
Please select a password:
Password:
Please re-type your password:
Password:
Password does not match. Please try again
```

Comment: I received an error message when I tried your result so you should address this I think Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Program Files\PYTHON\lib\getpass.py", line 92
    return fallback_getpass(prompt, stream)
GetPassWarning: Can not control echo on the terminal.
Warning: Password input may be echoed.
Password:

Answer (score 0):

This is a great way to learn about while loops

Ask for the values

```
password=raw_input("please select a password")
password_again=raw_input("please re-type your password")
```

Loop until they match

```
while password_again != password:
    print "They don't match please try again"
    password=raw_input("please select a password ")
    password_again=raw_input("please re-type your password ")
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not a loop, use `while True` and `break` :

```
while True:
    password=raw_input("please select a password")
    password_again=raw_input("please re-type your password")
    if password_again==password:
        print("password created")
        break
    else:
        print "Password does not match. Please try again"
```

Comment: Thanks guys, how is this different from pynewbies code (w/o the break statement)?

Comment: They both work and there are many more ways to accomplish what you are looking for.  I choose to not use a while true loop because I think they take a bit more time to get used to.

Comment: @user3386440 they do the same thing with different control flow, PyNEwbie's code is something more like a `do-while` loop in C/Cpp ;)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to make use of [`iter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#iter) function like this

```
password = raw_input("please select a password")
for re_password in iter(raw_input, password):
    print "Password does not match. Please try again :",
print "Password accepted!"
```

Comment: that might be a bit harder for the OP to understand at the moment ;)

Comment: @zhangxaochen Well, we all have to learn new things daily :) We can help him to understand if he asks questions after reading the doc :)